# Greenplum with Remote Hadoop Connect

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, greenplum

I am new to Greenplum DB. I have installed greenplum 4.3.7.2 version. Now i need to connect Hadoop system which is installed on another system. Please advise how should i installed **GPHDFS** and connect hadoop hdfs files.

Answer (score 0):

For hosts different for greenplum and hadoop, please do the following :

1. tar your gphd-1.1 directory on your hadoop Namenode and move it to DCA on Master (you can pick any directory to move this)
2. As gpadmin user on DCA gpscp gphd-1.1 tar file to all segment servers (use the same directory location as Master)
3. gpssh to all segment servers and untar the file (also untar on master)
4. For example if untar creates directory /home/gpadmin/gphd-1.1 then this becomes your gp_hadoop_home

Manish, may be the above helps, reference to the article here -
https://dwarehouse.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/greenplum-and-hadoop-hdfs-integration/#comment-479

please do post your findings.

Thanks.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.